# query working online but not on local machine

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, group-by

The Goal of my query is to identify all the suppliers with due invoices for this week. So the goal is just to have one entry per supplier, identifying the ones that should be showed this week.

SO my big question is why a query works online but not on local machine?

To get that i used the group by statement ant it was working so far! Now that i have a copy of what was online on my local server it stoped working as it should.

I have this query running online and everything works great:

```
$query_facturas_group = "SELECT TbFacturas.PkFacturas, TbFacturas.FkFornecedor, TbFacturas.FacturaData, TbFacturas.FacturaValor, TbFacturas.FacturaNumero, TbFacturas.FacturaEstado, TbFacturas.FacturaDataPagamento, Fornecedores.PkFornecedor, Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor, Fornecedores.EmailFornecedor 
                         FROM TbFacturas 
                         LEFT JOIN Fornecedores ON TbFacturas.FkFornecedor=Fornecedores.PkFornecedor 
                         WHERE TbFacturas.FacturaDataPagamento<'$pay_day' AND TbFacturas.FacturaEstado='0' AND TbFacturas.FacturaTrash='0'
                         GROUP BY TbFacturas.FkFornecedor 
                         ORDER BY Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor ASC";
```

The problem is that when I try to run it locally (to make some changes and upgrade it) it stopped working (no results).

Also, when I run it straight in the MySQL console, it works great...

I started removing parts of the code and it works (but not giving me the result I'm looking for...)

As soon as I remove the `GROUP BY` statement it starts working -  but not the expected result...

I tried using it with `SELECT DISTINCT` but with no success as it still shows Repeat Suppliers Name (`Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor` field).

Any guess??
 **UPDATE:**
 I noticed that there is another query in my project that does not work with `GROUP BY`

- PRINT SCREEN FROM THE RESULT IN HTML:

[image]

- PRINT SCREEN RESULT FROM CONSOLE

[image]

Comment: Is there any error or your expected result is not come?

Comment: @sadikhasan just no results... When i remove the group by statement it starts working... I've tried looking at it 100o times and I didn't find the error. The strangest part is that it works in sql console...

Comment: can you post more code and the expected results and the wrong results you getting

Comment: Try to import your live database in local and then test it because your locally data and live data may be mismatched.

Comment: "i have this query running online and everything works great:" i don't really believe that it 's can't be working great online because you are misusing MySQL extended GROUP BY feature which can cause **invalid** results this is a very common mistake/error on MySQL https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ .. Besides i advice you to read this "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: No images as data, images can not be used to reproduce the problem easy..

Comment: @sadikhasan that is what i did... (importing the db)

Comment: Your question is Unclear because we don't have access to enough database information and you have not been clear about your current results versus your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you are using two different version of mysql one oldest than 5.6 on server and one more recent locally  .. the group by behaviour is changed  starting fro d.6 and  do the fact 
 you are using group  by without aggregation function
 this is deprecated  in SQL  not allowed  in most recent version on mysql  and for the oldest versione the result for column values not involved  in group is unpredictable  ..

so if you just want distinct result  the you could use DISTINCT avoiding group by

```
$query_facturas_group = "SELECT DISTINCT TbFacturas.PkFacturas
    , TbFacturas.FkFornecedor
    , TbFacturas.FacturaData
    , TbFacturas.FacturaValor
    , TbFacturas.FacturaNumero
    , TbFacturas.FacturaEstado
    , TbFacturas.FacturaDataPagamento
    , Fornecedores.PkFornecedor
    , Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor
    , Fornecedores.EmailFornecedor 
  FROM TbFacturas 
  LEFT JOIN Fornecedores ON TbFacturas.FkFornecedor=Fornecedores.PkFornecedor 
  ORDER BY Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor ASC";
```

if you just want to reduce the number of rows the you should use aggreagtion function and group eg min() or max()

```
$query_facturas_group = "SELECT 
      min(TbFacturas.PkFacturas)
    , TbFacturas.FkFornecedor
    , min(TbFacturas.FacturaData)
    , min(TbFacturas.FacturaValor)
    , min(TbFacturas.FacturaNumero)
    , min(TbFacturas.FacturaEstado)
    , min(TbFacturas.FacturaDataPagamento)
    , min(Fornecedores.PkFornecedor)
    , min(Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor)
    , min(Fornecedores.EmailFornecedor )
  FROM TbFacturas 
  LEFT JOIN Fornecedores ON TbFacturas.FkFornecedor=Fornecedores.PkFornecedor 
  WHERE TbFacturas.FacturaDataPagamento<'$pay_day' AND TbFacturas.FacturaEstado='0' AND TbFacturas.FacturaTrash='0'
  GROUP BY TbFacturas.FkFornecedor 
  ORDER BY Fornecedores.NomeFornecedor ASC";
```

Comment: It makes sense! I'll try what you are saying, but the awkward part of it is that the same query works when in the Sql console, just doesn't work via PHP...

Comment: it works! but i still have no clue why it work on the console but not via php... thank you for your time!

Comment: In sqlconsole youn have a warning ??  ..the sqlconsole in which db version work?

Comment: LOCAL SERVER: innodb_version 5.7.23
protocol_version 10
slave_type_conversions 
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1
version 5.7.23
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os osx10.9
ONLINE: innodb_version
5.6.39-83.1
protocol_version
10
slave_type_conversions
version
10.1.36-MariaDB-cll-lve
version_comment
MariaDB Server
version_compile_machine
x86_64
version_compile_os
Linux
version_malloc_library
system jemalloc
version_ssl_library
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
wsrep_patch_version
wsrep_25.23

Comment: Cold be in online server you have a sql_mode setting different respect the local . You could check  the sql_mode .using . SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;